# Is there a way to hide the unread count badge in Mountain Lion's Mail.app?

Tags: email, macos

Mail.app used to have the ability to hide the unread count badge, as shown on [this 37signals blog post](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2213-turn-off-that-dock-unread-count):

[image]

It seems that [Apple has removed this in OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion](http://openradar.appspot.com/11898176). Is there any way to restore this functionality and remove the badge?

Comment: There must be a way as I had the Dock count turned off before the upgrade and it is still off after the upgrade. However, I don't see any further options.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

With the advent of Notification Center, the display of badges on any app can now be managed alongside display of banners, popups, and other notification-related settings.

Go to the `Notifications` preference pane in `System Preferences`, and select the Mail app from the list - the option to turn off the Dock badge should be there.

You may need to restart Mail for this change to take effect, though on 10.8.4 I do not.

Comment: That *totally* works, and didn't even occur to me. Many thanks.

Comment: Works for Skype as well! Awesome!

Comment: It turns out you need to quit Mail and restart for the Notification Center changes to take effect.